# Viewing a List of A Custom Class inside of Unity Inspector

Tags: unity

I have a Script with a custom class, which I've attached to a Unity GameObject:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[Serializable, Inspectable]
public class listOfBlends : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Inspectable]
    public List<individualBlend> blendList;
            
 }

    public class individualBlend 
{
    [Inspectable]
    public List<String> feemText;
    [Inspectable]
    public List<NeemData> listOfNeemsInBlend;
    public Boolean blendCompleted;
}
```

I'd like to be able to view this List inside of Unity, but the Inspector just shows me a List with items... and each item says, "No Inspector for 'Individual Blend'."

I'd like to be able to view the Individual Blends inside of the Inspector.  I've been researching Custom Editors, but am struggling with the learning curve... any advice on how to make the Individual Blends fully viewable in the Inspector?  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity uses the serializer to power its inspector views, so be sure to put the `[System.Serializable]` attribute on any type you want to display in the inspector that doesn't descend from `UnityEngine` classes like `MonoBehaviour` or `ScriptableObject`.

Here, the `[Serializable]` should be above `public class IndividualBlend` (type names start with an uppercase letter in standard C# nomenclature), not above `public class ListOfBlends : MonoBehaviour` (`MonoBehaciour` types are already serializable by default).

Comment: Thank you!!  It worked once I put "[Serializable, Inspectable]" above public class IndividualBlend.... just [Serializable] wasn't doing the trick.  THANK YOU!!

Comment: Ahh, are you using this for visual scripting? Just the [Serializable] attribute is enough for the regular inspector you get when selecting assets / scene objects, but if you want it to show up in the visual scripting interface you need [Inspectable]. It would be good to mention visual scripting in your question if that's the case.